# autosuggest textbox

Tags: autocomplete

Anybody knows the code for autosuggest textbox and how to implement it?

Comment: Language? Any other information?

Comment: Which platform? Browser? Windows?*nix?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

[Example1](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic34785.htm)

There are many ways, depends what you are programming (smart client, Web app ect...)
and what language...

Answer (score 0):

You can use compobox like auto suggest textbox if you have a list of the values. give us more info to give you more details.